# Core Data deleting objects

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm in the process of adding core data to my iPad app. My general procedure is to test out code by putting it in the app delegate. When I'm satisfied I have the code parsed properly, I move it to the appropriate method elsewhere in the app. This has worked so far with adding objects. But I'm having issues with deleting objects. I can delete them fine from the app delegate by selecting them and deleting them, and right now I am deleting them all upon app start just to keep the database clean until I have the core data code working.

So enough of my workflow. The issue I'm having now is deleting an object from the appropriate spot. Let's see if I can briefly describe my setup.

I have two classes, let's call them `Car` and `Tire` for the sake of this discussion. I don't know what the convention is, so I came up with my own, namely to add `C_` to the start of the name for the associated Core Data objects to store the objects associated with these objects. So I have two additional classes, `C_Car` and `C_Tire`. Each car can have several tires, so `Car` has a property `tires`, which is an `NSSet` of `Tire *`. Additionally `Car` has a property called `CarCD` of type `C_Car *`, and `Tire` has a property called `TireCD` of type `C_Tire *` so that each object can track its associated core data object (CD is for core data).

Xcode builds convenience methods to add or remove objects. Among these is the method to add a tire to a car. I use that thusly:

```
tire.tireCD = tireCD; //tire is an object of type Tire *, and tireCD is an object of type C_Tire *.
[self.carCD addTireObject:tireCD];//self.carCD is a property in my view controller of type CarCD *, and tireCD is a local object of type TireCD *.
```

Additionally, there is a convenience method to remove a tire from the car, `- (void)removeTireObject:(C_Tire *)value;`. I figured that everywhere in my view controller where I had:

```
[tireObject removeFromSuperview];//tireObject is a (Tire *) object.
```

I would simply change that to:

```
[carObject removeTireObject:tireObject.tireCD];
[tireObject removeFromSuperview];
```

The first line should remove the object from the `NSSet` on the core data object. The second line removes the object from the car object used in the app.

The problem is, I don't see any SQL being generated in the debugger window when this code is executed. Am I missing something?

Also, if you wish to comment on naming conventions, now is the time for me to adopt whatever is conventional.

Comment: Using po to query the CarCD object, I see the deletion is actually occurring. I think my error is that I wasn't deleting the TireCD object, only deleting its reference from the CarCD object.

Comment: I don't understand why you have 2 sets of classes (Car/Tire and C_Car/C_Tire). One managed object subclass for each entity should suffice.

Comment: Not all the properties of Car and Tire need to be saved to core data. C_Care and C_Tire contain only those properties needed to be saved. The other properties of Car and Tire are needed in the app but not core data. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: P.S. One is an NSMagagedObject. The other is not.

Comment: And Car/Tire are UIView's? Tire is a subview of Car?

Comment: Note that the you will see SQLite statements only when the managed object context is *saved*.

Comment: @MartinR, I realize that. My issue was that I was deleting the reference from the NSSet but not deleting the object. I added the [context deleteObject:] call and it worked as expected. Just a stupid oversight.

Comment: Yes, Car and Tire are UIView subclasses, and Tire is a subview of Car.

Comment: So your problem is solved or is there any question left? - (Btw. note that `deleteObject:tire` will automatically remove the tire from the car object if the Core Data "Delete Rule" is set to "Nullify".)

Comment: I'm deleting the C_Tire object. Core data seems to automatically remove the reference to it in C_Car, so I can omit the call to the convenience method `[carObject removeTireObject:tireObject.tireCD];`.

Comment: Yes, if the "Delete Rule" for the relationship from C_Tire to C_Car is set to "Nullify".

Comment: Yes. Problem solved. The only remaining issue is naming conventions for core data entities. Is there a convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This is a summary from above comments plus some additional remarks.)*

- `[car removeTireObject:tire]` just removes the tire from the car, it does not delete the tire object. To *delete* the object, call `[context deleteObject:tire]`.
- Deleting the tire will automatically remove it from the related car if the "Delete Rule" for the relationship from C_Tire to C_Car is set to "Nullify".
- Core Data changes are only written to disk if the context is *saved*, only then will you
  see SQLite debug output.

For the naming conventions, see ["Conventions"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) in "Programming with Objective-C". Some remarks:

- Using the underscore in class names is (as I think) unusual. Better class names for the managed object classes might be `CDCar`, `CDTire` or, if you follow the suggestion to use
  a three letter prefix, `XYZCar`, `XYZTire` where `XYZ` is some prefix chosen by you.
- I would use `CarView`, `TireView` for `UIView` subclasses.